# can't connect to sql database in godaddy server

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created a `connect.php` file in my website that I've hosted in `godaddy`, but when I include this file in my `index.php` page. All the content in the page went blank.

this is my connect.php file code

```
<?php
$host = 166.62.10.223;
$con = mysqli_connect("host","root","");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "error".mysqli_connect_errno();
}
?>
```

I really need some help

Comment: `mysqli_connect($host,"root","");`

Comment: if you working on live server then I think you need password as well. and BTW change your code to `$con = mysqli_connect($host,"root","");`

Comment: enable errors and see errors

Comment: one more suggestion `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` add it always. It will save you time and effort.

Comment: where can i look for server's password in godaddy hosting

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from

```
$host = 166.62.10.223;
$con = mysqli_connect("host","root","");
```

To

```
$host = 166.62.10.223;
$con = mysqli_connect($host,"root","");
```

And You need a password too if you are working on live server and username might not be `root` So replace them by actual values.

Example

```
$user = "liveserver_username"; //which is created in godaddy mysql wizard section
$password = "liverserver_password"; //which is created in godaddy mysql wizard section
$host = 166.62.10.223;

$con = mysqli_connect($host,"$user","$password");
```

more information on [how to create](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-setup/how-do-i-create-a-mysql-database-in-my-control-panel-cpanel) DB,User and password.

Comment: thanks for that...can you tell me how can i look for server's password in godaddy hosting

Comment: I think you should have login details for godaddy. if not then try forgot password approach